# Instagram post URL

Tags: php, instagram-api

I have a very simple script which helps me to display IG images on my website and it works great, but ideally I would like that once clicked the images would link to the actual post page rather than to the image source. Is there any way to have this tweaked?

PS: I know how to get rid of the fancybox in the link - but I don't know how and where to retrieve the actual post id / link from.

Here my current code:

```
    <?php

    function rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect( $api_url ){
        $connection_c = curl_init(); // initializing
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); // API URL to connect
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return the result, do not print
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
        $json_return = curl_exec( $connection_c ); // connect and get json data
        curl_close( $connection_c ); // close connection
        return json_decode( $json_return ); // decode and return
    }

    $access_token = 'my access token ';
    $username = 'my username';
    $user_search = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=" . $username . "&access_token=" . $access_token);
    // $user_search is an array of objects of all found users
    // we need only the object of the most relevant user - $user_search->data[0]
    // $user_search->data[0]->id - User ID
    // $user_search->data[0]->first_name - User First name
    // $user_search->data[0]->last_name - User Last name
    // $user_search->data[0]->profile_picture - User Profile Picture URL
    $limit = 8;
    $i = 0;
    // $user_search->data[0]->username - Username

    $user_id = $user_search->data[0]->id; // or use string 'self' to get your own media
    $return = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" . $user_id . "/media/recent?access_token=" . $access_token);

    //var_dump( $return ); // if you want to display everything the function returns

    foreach ($return->data as $post) {
        echo '<a href="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '" class="fancybox"><img src="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '" /></a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Use `var_dump($return);` and see what the API returns to you. May you find a parameter that links to the post.

Comment: Thx for the heads up - I've uncommented var_dump and I see a few references that contain the actual link to the post e.g. ["link"]=> string(40) "https://www.instagram.com/p/xxxx/"  <- actual link. So how can I convert this or use this in my a href?

Comment: Look at my answer. Have you written the code by yourself? I don't think so, because if you would have, you should know how to use it. Anyway, I hope I could describe it well in my answer. I really recommend you to try to understand whats going on. Copy + ?Paste won't help you for future problems. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thx again. Yes sure, absolutely not made by me - a script I've found online today: https://rudrastyh.com/php/instagram-api-recent-photos.html

Comment: No problem, Glad I could help. You simply have to look at the structure of your JSON answer. As you see, "standard_resolution" was a part from "images" - and since "images" is on the same level as "link", its like counting 1+1 together. You should be able to find every piece of information in this JSON. If you want to exercise yourself a bit, try for example to extract the "id" of the "user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're linking to `$post->images->standard_resolution->url`

Now, if we take a look at what the API returns (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)

```
},
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BWrVZ/",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "created_time": "1296710327",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
```

As you can see, on the top there's `link` - All you have to do is to change your href to this link instead of the image URL.

So change:

```
 echo '<a href="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '" class="fancybox"><img src="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '" /></a>';
```

to:

```
 echo '<a href="' . $post->link . '" class="fancybox"><img src="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '" /></a>';
```

And it should work. Hope it helped.

Comment: . $post->link .  was all i needed! Thank a lot Twinfriends